# Autofiler for Or Condition in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am filtering the data using .Autofilter in an Excel Sheet as follows

```
if bProds = True then
    .AutoFilter 4,"<>*strip*",2,"<>*Strip*"
    .AutoFilter 8,"Product",2,"product"
else
    .AutoFilter 8, "<>Product", 1, "<>product"
    .AutoFilter 4,"*strip*",2,"*Strip*"
end if
```

The result set is rows where both the Autofilter criteria met.
In the else part I want to make a condition such that result is the rows where it does not contain product/Product in column 8 or if it contains strip/Strip in column 4.

Since autofilters returns if both conditions were met, the above code don't work. Any way to make it work like my requirement?

Test data also available from [this drive.google.com link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1fvlZnQ12vodFFqjAHaODXcF0CYFkahBKGUBE7EMt8Uc)

Sheet 1:

```
  Col1      Col2   Col3  Col4    Col5    Col6     Col7     Col8
---------   ----   ----  -----   -----   ----     ----     -----
1/07/2015    3      3    Word1   word2   AB       Hello    Product
1/13/2015    2      1    word2   word1   AB       hello    product
1/13/2015    2      1    COzier  USA     Bill     Allice   Assembly
1/14/2015    3      4    TOny    USA     Bill     Allice   Wrox
1/20/2015    2      1    Shawn   USA     gerard   amy      Product
1/23/2015    2      1    Wilcox  Sanzer  Francis  Bob      Assembly
1/26/2015    3      5    Justin  Langer  Go       febrand  Citrix
```

Sheet 2:

```
  Col1      Col2   Col3  Col4    Col5    Col6     Col7     Col8
---------   ----   ----  -----   -----   ----     ----     -----
1/20/2015    2      1    Shawn   USA     gerard   amy      Product
```

Sheet 3:

```
  Col1      Col2   Col3  Col4    Col5    Col6     Col7     Col8
---------   ----   ----  -----   -----   ----     ----     -----
1/07/2015    3      3    Word1   word2   AB       Hello    Product
1/13/2015    2      1    word2   word1   AB       hello    product
1/13/2015    2      1    COzier  USA     Bill     Allice   Assembly
1/14/2015    3      4    TOny    USA     Bill     Allice   Wrox
1/23/2015    2      1    Wilcox  Sanzer  Francis  Bob      Assembly
1/26/2015    3      5    Justin  Langer  Go       febrand  Citrix
```

Comment: I don't think you can achieve this with AutoFilter unless you use a helper column. [Advanced Filter](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Filter-by-using-advanced-criteria-4c9222fe-8529-4cd7-a898-3f16abdff32b#bmexample3) can achieve this if that's an acceptable solution

Comment: Can you provide minimal test data for before-and-after?

Comment: I can use any construct. Since the existing code is using .Autofilter I am just checking if its possible to do using .Autofilter. No Problem using .AdvanceFilter as long as it achieves what I want..:).I made a test file `https://drive.google.com/open?id=1fvlZnQ12vodFFqjAHaODXcF0CYFkahBKGUBE7EMt8Uc`

Comment: In the sheet, Columns D,E with Word1 and Word2 have Product keyword in column H. I need the Output similar in Sheet3. Sheet 2 is output of my first `if` statement. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Sub autoFilter1()    'Column 8 = "Product"
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    ws.UsedRange.Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    If Not ws.AutoFilter Is Nothing Then ws.ShowAllData

    ws.UsedRange.AutoFilter 8, "product"
End Sub

Public Sub autoFilter2()    'Column 8 <> "Product" OR Column 4 = "Word1"
    Dim ws As Worksheet, vRng As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    ws.UsedRange.Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    If Not ws.AutoFilter Is Nothing Then ws.ShowAllData

    ws.UsedRange.AutoFilter 8, "<>product"
    Set vRng = ws.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        ws.ShowAllData
    ws.UsedRange.AutoFilter 4, "word1"
    Set vRng = Union(vRng, ws.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))
    ws.UsedRange.AutoFilter

    ws.UsedRange.Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    vRng.Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    ws.Cells(1).Select
End Sub
```

---

[image: multiAutoFilter]

Comment: Sry about that let me test and get back

Comment: This is not exactly what I want. may be I am not clear in my problem statement as you said.Eg:- In my Dataset  we filter based on column 8 and column 4. I need to separate out the records containing `'Product'` in Column 8 into Sheet A and records with non product values in Column 8 into Sheet B. Alongside, in Sheet B I need to have records with `word1` in Column 4 though they have 'Product' in column 8.  The `.Autofilter` condition in my original post does a logical 'AND' of my else condition. But I need an 'OR' like behavior as I mentioned. Hope I am clear

Comment: I'm still unclear about the expected result (probably because of invalid test data): you are saying _non product values in Column 8 in Sheet B_, yet your Sheet B contains only one record, which is "product". I updated your initial post to include the sample data you provided in the external file, but I'd need to have the basic setup: 1) the initial list of records 2) the expected result - 2 outcomes based on 2 criteria, from the initial recordset

Comment: Okay, let me rephrase the problem. In Sheet A I want to have the records with `Product/product` in Column8 . In Sheet B I want all records **WITHOUT** product in column8(like Assembly, wrox,Citrix) + records with `word1` in column4 even though they have product in column8. pls let me know if it helps

Comment: I made an update for the AutoFilter to use the Or operator when combining criteria for Col 4 and Col 8